# Nested javascript invocation

Tags: javascript

So recently, i often to come across instagram post that invokes javascript i.e. like this --> **foo.bar().baz().qux();**. The insertion of parameters can be done on so many levels. However from what i have just learned, in nested object literal, we can only do **foo.bar.baz.qux();** or only **one** parameter insertion. Can anyone show how to create nested object literals that can be invoked like this --> **foo.bar().baz().qux();** ?
^cheers,

Comment: Instagram posts invoke JavaScript now? This is essentially just a function that returns an Object, that has a function in it, that again returns an Object with a function in it.

Comment: Each of those methods returns object, probably `this`. It's so called chaining http://jscriptpatterns.blogspot.com/2012/09/chaining-pattern.html

Comment: it was a photo. of course, XD can you show how to create one? im kind of lost here. ive just learned programming. but sometimes random confusion comes across.

Comment: Nina Scholz Taking properties. How to build one? *cheers,

Comment: Oh GOD! i got duplicate mark right away!... which mean s its answered.. stackoverflow is the ultimate.. thx!! im happy now..